# can i show ad's inside ion-content using admob in ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I implement ad-mob in our project to show ad's (bottom and interstitial) ads working fine but in our project we also need Native ads inside div or inside ion-content can we create it in ionic .[image: example image]